# How can I put arguments from controller in a CakePHP virtual field (haversine formula)?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I want to use the haversine formula in my CakePHP find queries to return locations for a given radius and latitude/longitude pair. I just read about virtual fields in CakePHP but in my case I need to pass those 3 parameters. How can I solve this ?

```
public $virtualFields = array(

'distance' => '( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( Location.latitude ) ) *     cos( radians( Location.longitude ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin(   radians( Location.latitude ) ) ) )',

);
```

The virtual field above works fine and it returns the distance from the point in the table to the values specified in the formula directly (37,-122). Now how can I change this values on the fly!?

Answer (score 1):

It worked like this for me:

```
$this->Location->virtualFields['distance'] = '( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $latitude .      ') 

) * cos( radians( Location.latitude ) ) * cos( 

radians( Location.longitude ) - radians(' . $longitude . ') ) + sin( radians(' . 

$latitude . ') ) * sin( radians( 

Location.latitude ) ) ) )';
```

It dynamically assigns the virtual field on-the-fly from the Controller.